# Как посчитать количество повторений каждого значения в массиве, и отдельно вывести то которое повторяется чаще всего Swift

Tags: swift

```swift
let numbers = [5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 6, 9, 6, 5]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне кажется, тут вообще ничего сложного. Напишите пожалуйста ваш код и укажите, что именно не получается.